Setting notes in a midi files to a custom grid from another midi file
I'm facing problems trying to custom quantize a midi file,
this is my best script so far using mido, it is not working properly
both the "groove.mid" & "1.mid" have same tempo & length.
is there a simpler library that can do this or is there a way to fix this code?
import mido

# Function to extract note-on timings in ticks from a MIDI file
def extract_note_on_timings(midi_file):
    midi = mido.MidiFile(midi_file)
    ticks_per_beat = midi.ticks_per_beat
    note_on_timings = []

    for track in midi.tracks:
        current_time = 0
        for msg in track:
            current_time += msg.time
            if msg.type == 'note_on' and msg.velocity > 0:
                note_on_timings.append(current_time)  # Store time in ticks

    return note_on_timings

# Function to align note timings in target MIDI file to closest timings in custom groove
def align_note_timings(custom_groove_timings, target_midi_file, output_file):
    target_midi = mido.MidiFile(target_midi_file)
    new_midi = mido.MidiFile()
    new_track = mido.MidiTrack()
    new_midi.tracks.append(new_track)

    custom_groove_index = 0

    for track in target_midi.tracks:
        for msg in track:
            if msg.type == 'note_on' and msg.velocity > 0 and custom_groove_index < len(custom_groove_timings):
                # Find closest timing from custom groove and adjust note timing
                closest_time = min(custom_groove_timings, key=lambda x: abs(x - msg.time))
                new_track.append(msg.copy(time=closest_time))
                custom_groove_index += 1
            else:
                new_track.append(msg.copy(time=msg.time))

    new_midi.save(output_file)
    print(f"Saved aligned MIDI file to {output_file}")

# Example usage with your paths:
custom_groove_file = r'groove.mid'
target_midi_file = r'1.mid'
output_midi_file = r'output.mid'

# Extract custom groove timings from your custom groove MIDI file
custom_groove_timings = extract_note_on_timings(custom_groove_file)

# Align note timings in target MIDI file to custom groove timings and save as output MIDI file
align_note_timings(custom_groove_timings, target_midi_file, output_midi_file)


Just in case you're OK with C# instead of Python, you can use my DryWetMIDI library which already has built-in Quantizer tool allowing you to snap data to any desired grid.
